# FATAL [ 0] gearman_packet_unpack_header:invalid command value

Tags: php, ubuntu, gearman

I'm trying to run the [example Gearman worker from their documentation](http://gearman.org/index.php?id=gearman_php_extension) (see below), but every time I do I get a slew of errors in my Gearman log file like this:  `FATAL [   0] gearman_packet_unpack_header:invalid command value`. When I run the Gearman client (again, their own example), it doesn't seem to change anything. Nothing happens.

Here is the sample worker code that is failing

```
# Create our worker object.
$worker= new GearmanWorker();

# Add default server (localhost).
$worker->addServer();

# Register function "reverse" with the server.
$worker->addFunction("reverse", "reverse_fn");

while (1)
{
  print "Waiting for job...\n";

  $ret= $worker->work();
  if ($worker->returnCode() != GEARMAN_SUCCESS)
    break;
}

# A much simple reverse function
function reverse_fn($job)
{
  $workload= $job->workload();
  echo "Received job: " . $job->handle() . "\n";
  echo "Workload: $workload\n"; 
  $result= strrev($workload);
  echo "Result: $result\n";
  return $result;
}
```

`>php -i`:

```
extension version   1.0.2
libgearman version  0.29
Default TCP Host    localhost
Default TCP Port    4730
```

`>gearmand -V`:

`gearmand 0.29`

How do I correctly configure Gearman to work? libgearman is the same version as gearmand, and my PECL extension is the most-recent stable version. I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I was able to tell, the PECL extension for Gearman as version 1.0.2 does not work with Gearman version 0.29. I updated Gearman and libgearman both to version 0.33, and as soon as I did my extension was working.

Comment: I've run into similar, though not identical issues. I've given up with the PECL extension, and am in the process of switching to PEAR's Net_Gearman - since it is PHP, I expect it to be much more resilient to version/architecture differences.